# Ring $R$ that contains a field $F$ as a subring: Can $R$ not be an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a ring that contains a field $F$ as a subring. Is it possible for $R$ **not** to be an integral domain? So far the only example I know is $R=F[x]$, but then $R$ is an integral domain.

I am looking for some other counterexamples.

Comment: Hint: Mod out that ring by $x^2$.

Comment: What about $F\times F$?

Comment: $M_n(F)$?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Any ring of characteristic $p$ contains $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: Examples above show it to be false.  But this reminds me of another problem for you to think about: Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $F \subset R$ is an infinite field.  Let $I, J_1, J_2, \dots, J_n$ be ideals of $R$ with $n \geq 2$.  If $I \subset \cup J_k$ then $I \subset J_k$ for some $k$.  That's about the 'domain-iest' you can require.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of answering this question with an answer rather than comments ... Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a field.

- Take the ring $\mathbf{k}[x]/(x^2)$. This will have $\mathbf{k}$ as a subring, but is not a domain since $x$ is a zero divisor.
- Take the ring $\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{k}$, which has the diagonal subring $\{ (a,a) : a \in \mathbf{k} \}$ as a subring isomorphic to $\mathbf{k}$, but has the zero divisors $(0,1)(1,0)=0$.
- More generally, take the ring $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbf{k})$ of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbf{k}$.
- If a unital ring has positive characteristic $p$, then it'll contain a copy of the field with $p$ elements. So any example of a unital non-domain with characteristic $p$ will work too.